If I downgrade my DMARC policy in the future, will it have bad effect on deliverability?
I have a domain that is not being used to send email, and so I was planning to just set the DMARC policy to "p=reject", remove everything from the SPF record, etc, to encourage recipients to reject all emails.
However, I am wondering what would happen if I decided to send email from this domain in the future.  I would want to change the DMARC policy, but would changing it after having it at "reject" for a long time cause a problem with deliverability?

Simply having a DMARC policy (p=none) is enough for deliverability. The only way it might detrimentally impact deliverability would be if someone spoofed your domain and sent spam from it when you didn't have it set to "reject" or "quarantine".
